# Input apenas com V ou F

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

É possível colocar um input onde ele receba apenas (V) ou (F)?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#resposta_vouf").mask("(a)");   
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="resposta_vouf" />
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar um `input type='checkbox'`? Quando marcado = true, do contrário = false.

Comment: Se a minha resposta lhe agradou, não esqueça de aceitá-la. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui. Primeiro comecei a partir [desta outra do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955724/540552). Depois disso, experimentei o código e cheguei nisso:

```js
var valorSalvo = 'F';

$('#textbox').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
   var atual = $("#textbox").val().replace(/v/g, 'V').replace(/f/g, 'F').replace(/[^VF]/g, '');
   var ultimo = atual.substring(atual.length - 1);
   var primeiro = atual.substring(0, 1);
   var novo = ultimo === valorSalvo ? primeiro : ultimo;
   if (novo === 'V' || novo === 'F') valorSalvo = novo;
   $("#textbox").val(valorSalvo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="F" />
```

O algoritmo funciona assim:

1. O campo inicia com o valor `F`. Não é imprescindível que ele inicie com um valor válido, mas é bastante recomendável.
2. Inicialmente, o programa permitirá que o textbox possa ser alterado da forma que for (seja ao digitar ou ao usar <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>), mas a alteração não será visível e nem tomará efeito porque o evento (que redefinirá o conteúdo do input) é disparado imediatamente após isso.
3. Os caracteres `v`s e `f`s minúsculos são convertidos para maiúsculos e os diferentes de `V` e `F` são removidos.
4. O algoritmo tenta determinar se o texto antigo está no começo ou no final do texto novo para saber se o que foi digitado ou colado está no início ou no final, e usa isso para detectar qual é o novo caractere que interessa.
5. Se o texto resultante for `F` ou `V`, este texto será aplicado ao input (sobreescrevendo o que lá estava). Em caso contrário (pode ocorrer de o novo texto ser vazio, por exemplo), o texto anterior é aplicado (também sobreescrevendo o que está no input) e portanto resultando na rejeição da alteração.

Há um detalhe importante a se notar: Como eu não estou fazendo filtragem de teclas, tal como seria o caso se eu usasse `keydown` ou `keypress`, então eu não preciso me preocupar com backspace e teclas especiais. Como resultado, esse código aí funciona com <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> e também não bloqueia nenhuma tecla especial tal como <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> e setas direcionais.